# Android studio XML Parse Error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, realm

I update Manifest file encoding utf-8 to utf16. After some changes, I want to come back utf-8 but I have this error now. I don't know what can I do? I clean project and rebuilt but it not solved.I put my manifest xml and build.gradle(app)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.imdbfilm">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FilmOzellikleri" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.imdbfilm"
            minSdkVersion 23
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
        testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
        androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
        androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: go to merger manifest option available in manifest and check the error..

Comment: add the error code or logcat. whatever you have

Comment: @TouhidulIslam ERROR: Failed to parse XML in /Users/zorroxz/AndroidStudioProjects/imdbfilm/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/Users/zorroxz/AndroidStudioProjects/imdbfilm/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 39; Content is not allowed in prolog.
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Sounds like one of your XMLs got corrupted.